# convert XAML to c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to convert the followinf code to c# code.
There is a tool to do it automatically?
thank you

```
 <ListView Name="listView" Margin="0,0,0,164">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Devise" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=devise}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Libelle" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=label}" Width="120" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Unite" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=unite}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Achat" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=achatBanque}" Width="80" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Vente" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=venteBanque}" Width="80" />    
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: @vcsjones: no, XAML does not define meaning of the classes. It just defines the structure, and there's equivalent C# code that creates the same tree of objects. Actually, what `XamlReader`/`BamlReader` is doing.

Answer (score 13):

I thought doing this shouldn't be that hard (using CodeDOM), so I started working on a solution. The source is available [at github](https://github.com/svick/XAML-conversion). It's really just a beginning, it doesn't support many of the features of XAML, but it works for the code in the question.

If you are serious about this, you can work on that code further.

The XAML in the question produces the following output, that seems to work:

```
private ListView Get()
{
    ListView listView = new ListView();
    listView.Name = "listView";
    listView.Margin = ((Thickness)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Thickness)).ConvertFromInvariantString("0,0,0,164")));
    GridView gridView = new GridView();
    GridViewColumn gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    gridViewColumn.Header = "Devise";
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString("devise")));
    gridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = binding;
    gridViewColumn.Width = 80D;
    gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);
    GridViewColumn gridViewColumn2 = new GridViewColumn();
    gridViewColumn2.Header = "Libelle";
    Binding binding2 = new Binding();
    binding2.Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString("label")));
    gridViewColumn2.DisplayMemberBinding = binding2;
    gridViewColumn2.Width = 120D;
    gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn2);
    GridViewColumn gridViewColumn3 = new GridViewColumn();
    gridViewColumn3.Header = "Unite";
    Binding binding3 = new Binding();
    binding3.Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString("unite")));
    gridViewColumn3.DisplayMemberBinding = binding3;
    gridViewColumn3.Width = 80D;
    gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn3);
    GridViewColumn gridViewColumn4 = new GridViewColumn();
    gridViewColumn4.Header = "Achat";
    Binding binding4 = new Binding();
    binding4.Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString("achatBanque")));
    gridViewColumn4.DisplayMemberBinding = binding4;
    gridViewColumn4.Width = 80D;
    gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn4);
    GridViewColumn gridViewColumn5 = new GridViewColumn();
    gridViewColumn5.Header = "Vente";
    Binding binding5 = new Binding();
    binding5.Path = ((PropertyPath)(TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PropertyPath)).ConvertFromInvariantString("venteBanque")));
    gridViewColumn5.DisplayMemberBinding = binding5;
    gridViewColumn5.Width = 80D;
    gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn5);
    listView.View = gridView;
    return listView;
}
```

Comment: ...great start, how to add 3rd party references ?

Comment: If you mean how to handle types from 3rd party assemblies, that should work after an update I made to the code today using the normal `xmlns:something="clr-namespace:Something"` syntax. See example in the demo app.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a tool to do this automatically, but in general you can take attributes and change them to setting properties. You may lose the automatic conversion for certain types though, but in those cases you'd just need to determine the type of the property and use that (such as Margin below).

For example:

```
var gridView = new GridView();

gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() {
    Header = "Devise",
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding() { Path = "devise" },
    Width = 80
});
// ...

var listView = new ListView() {
    Name = "listView",
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 164),
    View = gridView
};
```

Comment: that's great for the vanilla sample but the benefit of the converter is for the numerous 3rd party controls where the straightforward approach above does not help! is there a way to look at the "DOM" at run time ?

Comment: @Kumar - That may be possible, but you wouldn't be able to decompile StaticResourceExtension. I'm sure there are other issues that one would run into (such as implicit styles & templates, and resources).