# How can XAML-Code be converted to C#-Code

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

There are many of the same questions on stackoverflow which has very **low** and **old** answers, now I would like to ask the question again:

**Is there any way to convert XAML source code to C# source code?**

Comment: please provide details of what you are trying to convert. Fom my knowledge there is no automatic convert. But you can do everything in code, if not more that you can do in xaml. They wy you build the elements and how the code looks is way different thoug

Comment: Possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930754/convert-xaml-to-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no automatic conversion tool.

Basically, you create an element first, assign its properties and then add it to the Form.

Example for building a Grid and assigning some children:

in xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Bitconomy.views.mining_view">
  <ContentView.Content x:Name="MineStack">
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

generation of Grid:

```cs
int counter = 0;
// create grid element
Grid example = new Grid();
// create row for adding to rowdefinitions
RowDefinition standardRow = new RowDefinition();
GridLength size = new GridLength(0.3, GridUnitType.Star);
standardRow.Height = size;
// add child element
example.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
example.Children.Add(new Resource_Mine_View("Stone"), 0,counter);
// add child element
example.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
counter++;
example.Children.Add(new Resource_Mine_View("Wood"),0,counter);
// add child element
example.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
counter++;
example.Children.Add(new Resource_Mine_View("Food"), 0, counter);
// add grid to layout
MineStack.Children.Add(example)
```

(0 beeing the column and counter beeing the assigned row)